# What updates to resolve this issue with certificates in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, certificate

I have the following error in my Google Chrome browser when accessing certain sites:
`Your connection is not private` returned the following error code `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

[this is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adjci.png)

I just installed **Windows 7 Home Premium** version on my notebook and I came across this error, due to not having installed the updates, my configuration is basic and I would not want to go out installing a lot of updates until I find a specific one that solves the problem (I know which is because of updates because on another machine I installed the system, presented the due errors of unauthorized certificates, installed all the recommended updates and solved the problem)

I've tried to find the **specific** update on the *Microsoft Update Catalog* website but to no avail

### EDIT

When trying to perform updates through Windows Update, I return this: **Windows was unable to check for new updates**

*Error(s) found:*

Code 80072EFE Unknown error on Windows Update

Comment: Is W7 full updated using Windows Updates?

Comment: By default comes the tool that does this, Windows Update, but it has the Microsoft online catalog, where I can search for the update reference and install it manually

Comment: so I don't know what the update reference is for this certificate error

Comment: Why not run windows update?

Comment: my machine's settings are very weak, I install the system and stay calm, but after installing the updates it ends up slowing down the machine, when starting up, when opening installed programs, when executing processes, and it uses 100% CPU usage, this only after installing the updates recommended by Windows Update (we agree that it recommends unnecessary updates, but because it does not know the update specifies that it solves the problem it ends up showing these symptoms)

Comment: Certificate trusts in browsers are usually maintained by the browser maker. What CA is your system failing to recognize?

Comment: You will have to update Windows 7 fully in order to solve your problem.  There is no getting around that requirement

Comment: Unfortunately that is what I am doing now, there is no other way!